# How do I compare two results choosing unique items?

Tags: mysql

So I have a query that gives me a nice list of items. I want to run the query again with different parameters to get a second list of items.

Then I want to compare the two lists. I want to see that items that are in the second query but not in the first query.

I also want to do the same thing but find the items that ARE common.

I essentially want to run a UNIX comm command, and I've been running the queries separately and then doing that. But I would like to automate the process.

How do I do this? I realize this is an beginner question but I just don't even know where to start.

```
SELECT DISTINCT A0
from shakedata2
WHERE PLAY_ID=489 OR PLAY_ID=490
GROUP BY A0;
```

So I would like to run two queries, outputting either the items that are in one query but not the other OR in other cases outputting the items that are common to both queries.

Comment: Sounds like a scenario where `OUTER JOIN`s can help.

Answer (score 1):

To get the common items of your queries you can use `EXISTS`:

```
select q1.columnname from query1 q1
where exists (
  select 1 from query2 q2
  where q2.columnname = q1.columnname
)
```

or an `INNER JOIN`:

```
select q1.columnname 
from query1 q1 inner join query2 q2
on q2.columnname = q1.columnname
```

To get the items from query1 that do not exist in query2 use `NOT EXISTS` or a `LEFT JOIN` and get only the rows where there is not a corresponding value of query2:

```
select q1.columnname 
from query1 q1 left join query2 q2
on q2.columnname = q1.columnname
where q2.columnname is null
```

or with `NOT IN`:

```
select q1.columnname 
from query1 q1 
where q1.columnname not in (
  select q2.columnname 
  from query2 q2 
)
```

You can add to the select statement of all the above queries the keyword `distinct` if there is a case of duplicate results.

Comment: This is incredibly helpful. Thank you. How do I specify my output from the query to go into a specific table or column. That is the conceptual part I don't understand. q1 is a temporary table of some kind? does it retain the A0 column name from the original table? This is the conceptual problem I have. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: You can use table names instead of query1 or query2. Or for example you can do this: `select q1.A0
from (
  SELECT A0
  from shakedata2
  WHERE PLAY_ID=489
) q1 INNER JOIN (
  SELECT A0
  from shakedata2
  WHERE PLAY_ID=490
) q2 
on q2.A0 = q1.A0`

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think this works. I don't understand how to do this. I want the items in q2.A0 that are NOT in q1.A0. So I want to go through each item in q2.a0. If it is in q1.A0, I want to remove it from the list. The final list will have only items that are unique to q2.A0.

Comment: All the above code is general solutions that would work in any case. It can be simplified. In your case the simpler most readable way is with NOT IN: `SELECT A0 from shakedata2 WHERE PLAY_ID=490 AND A0 NOT IN (SELECT A0 from shakedata2 WHERE PLAY_ID=489 )`

Comment: yes, I understand now. thank you so much. That is beautiful.

Answer (score 1):

To find all items for one set that are not part of the second set, you can use outer joins within mysql itself:

```
select  a.*
from    shakedata2 a
left join shakedata2 b
on a.play_id = b.play_id
and (a.x1 = 1 and a.x2 = 2)
and (b.y1 = 2 and b.y2 = 1)
where b.play_id is null
```

`x1`, `x2` and so forth are example fields you may want to query.

To find records that match both criteria, you can use an inner join or just change `is null` into `is not null` in the above query.